# Ruby eval method errors if there is timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I am trying to make hash out of string as so:

```
hash = eval({"name"=>["name", "changed"], "updated_at"=>[nil, Tue, 31 Dec 2013 09:39:29 EET +02:00]})
```

but this gives a following error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):19: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ']'
..."updated_at"=>[nil, Tue, 31 Dec 2013 09:39:29 EET +02:00]})
...                               ^
(irb):19: Invalid octal digit
..._at"=>[nil, Tue, 31 Dec 2013 09:39:29 EET +02:00]})
...                               ^
```

How can i proceed with this? Thank you all.

Comment: Your hash is not correct syntactically. Give us the original hash string also. This is `[nil, Tue, 31 Dec 2013 09:39:29 EET +02:00]` wrong.

Comment: And rightfully so .. that's *invalid* syntax. You likely wanted a *string* representing the date/time.

Comment: I am saving the hash string to the database like so:

changes_to_users.change_hash = @user.changes.to_s

And later i am trying to convert this string from database to hash as so: 

hash = eval(change_hash)

Comment: @samiljin That just won't work at all and it results in *invalid syntax*: `to_s` is *not* necessarily reversible (especially through `eval`, which is just *bad code* when uses like this!). It only works in some cases: and, not here. If you *must* save a a denormalized data-structure, at least use an *existing serialization format* like JSON (or even Marshal or XML).

Comment: @samiljin I suspect that it would be better to *normalize* the data such that there is an `updated_at` *field* in the database. Since you're using RoR, this is how it is *normally* done so you're likely just not updating (or reading) the attributes correctly. e.g. see [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes).

Answer (score 2):

write this code as :-

```
hash = eval({"name"=>["name", "changed"], "updated_at"=>[nil, "Tue, 31 Dec 2013 09:39:29 EET +02:00"]})
```

or

```
hash = eval({"name"=>["name", "changed"], "updated_at"=>[nil, Date.today]})
```